# How to make a login(Username & Password) in bootstrap model?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXrL1.jpg
How to make a login(Username & Password) in bootstrap model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body class="w3-container">

<h2>W3.CSS Login Modal</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn w3-green w3-large">Login</button>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-8 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

    <div class="w3-center"><br>
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-container w3-padding-8 w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="img_avatar4.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:30%" class="w3-circle w3-margin-top">
    </div>

    <form class="w3-container" action="form.asp">
      <div class="w3-section">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="usrname" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button class="w3-btn-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" type="submit">Login</button>
        <input class="w3-check w3-margin-top" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-btn w3-red">Cancel</button>
      <span class="w3-right w3-padding w3-hide-small">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hope i helped don't forget to mark tick on my answer :)

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer make give me a right tick on the left side of my answer(below the vote section).